# With how many resources can a user log into a standard compliant XMPP server?

Tags: xmpp

Simple question: is there any restriction on the number of concurrent logins using the same bare JID but different resources in the XMPP standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is implementation-defined, with no set maximum in the RFCs.  However, [RFC 6120, section 7.6.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-7.6.2.1) says:

> If the account has reached a limit on the number of simultaneous
> connected resources allowed, the server MUST return a  stanza error (Section [8.3.3.18](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-8.3.3.18)).

```xml
S: <iq id='tn281v37' type='error'>
     <error type='wait'>
       <resource-constraint
         xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
     </error>
   </iq>
```

Therefore, it is not true that there is *no* limit, just that each server installation can make different decisions about what the limit is.

Comment: This is a reasonable extension of @Alex's answer, therefore I'm going to mark this one as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

unlimited, there is no restriction in the RFCs

Comment: The answer is correct, however @Joe elaborates a little bit more therefore I'm going to mark his answer as the correct one, but vote this one up, too.